# MySQL SELECT sometimes found nothing even it exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP script that runs every 3 hours that gets the amazon mws orders and save it into my database.

But before I insert an order into my table, I check first if the order exist

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM orders WHERE transaction_id = "XXXXXXXXX"
```

But sometimes even if an order exist, the query will return 0. If return 0, I will insert the order into my table and it will end up duplicating the data.

This instance happens to me in my other PHP scripts and I don't understand the issue.

Comment: You can use REPLACE instead of INSERT to avoid duplicated key but data will be replaced and transaction_id must be primary key. No matter if it is the same thing. Check before why select return 0. Try with transactions, you have an issue here. Can you provide some code.

Comment: Make an unique index against `transaction_id`

Comment: What us output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE orders;`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something called as **EXISTS** for checking whether a row exists or not in your case order.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ...);
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE condition);
```

Answer (score 0):

If  your database uses master-slave mode，you can try to force the master to query.

You can also use the “INSERT IGNORE INTO orders ....” to ignore duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an error in your MySQL query. I created a test table and write some code to print the result of the query which is working correctly.

> You may not be using the quotations properly as this is the error most
>   of the time when you are working with queries in PHP

Here is the code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "practise";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno());
} 

$sql = "SELECT count(*) from test where title='Hello'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$new =mysqli_fetch_array($result);
 echo $new[0];

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

And:

[Image of the table where I am executing the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM3kg.png)

The output against the MySQL query is:

```
2
```

The code works perfectly. If you have any other question, please share your code and I'll be more than happy to help you.